# How to fit a background image to the screen?

Tags: html, css

I tried this css code:

```
background: url(bg.jpg) center center no-repeat fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

But still the background image's height is larger than the viewport. Why is this happening? Please don't just give me the codes, explain too.

Comment: `cover` fills all the available space (potentially cropping the image), if you want to keep the image inside the area you want `contain`

Comment: Actually I didn't want "contain". I wanted my background image to fill all the viewport without being cropped. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size):

> **cover** A keyword that is the inverse of contain. Scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't
>   get squished). The image "covers" the entire width or height of the
>   container. When the image and container have different dimensions, the
>   image is clipped either left/right or top/bottom.

It is taller than the viewport because that was the only way to make it wide enough to fill the viewport without changing the aspect ration.

Use `100% 100%` to scale it while breaking the aspect ratio.

---

You might also have to set `background-attachment: fixed` to force it to scale to the window instead of the body element if the content of the document makes the body taller than the viewport.

Comment: After his edit, it sounds like he's actually after `contain`.

Comment: @DBS — Sounds like 100% 100% to me still.